# Accessing table calls for writing and reading

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to insert the options in the last cell of the table. Please let me know how to access the properties of a Combobox for reading and writing.

```js
var DeviceNames = new Array ("Dev1", "Dev2");

function addoption(select_id, text, rowcnt) {
    
    select=document.getElementById(select_id);
    
    var row = select.rows[rowcnt-1];
    var rowObj = row.cells[4];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.innerHTML = text;
    option.value = 1;
    rowObj.options.add(option);
}

function loadcombo(select_id, option_array, cnt)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < option_array.length; i++)
    {
        addoption (select_id, option_array[i], cnt);
    }
}

function addRow(tableID) {  
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  

  //Column 1    
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
  cell1.innerHTML = rowCount+1;  
  //Column 2  
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");  
  element2.type = "text";  
  cell2.appendChild(element2); 

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);  
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");  
  element3.type = "text";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);      

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");  
  element4.type = "text";  
  cell4.appendChild(element4); 

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var element5 = document.createElement("select");
  cell5.appendChild(element5);

  loadcombo(tableID, DeviceNames, rowCount);
                
}
```

```html
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add Entry" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Insert Entry" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" name="button1" value="Delete Entery" onclick="removeRow('button1')" />           
          <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">  
               <TR>
                    <TD></TD>
               </TR>               
          </TABLE>
```

I want to insert the options in the last cell of the table. Please let me know how to access the properties of a Combobox for reading and writing.

Comment: Do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: No, but nothing comes up on Combobox.

Comment: Try creating a code snippet in the question to reproduce the problem ([how to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5217142)).  I think you should be calling `.add` on the select element, but have no idea where the select object gets its `rows` property from,  or why you are using it. You may have a broader issue with  what you've posted.

Comment: @traktor added a snippet. Please guide me know how to access the Combobox cell to inert options.

Answer (score 0):

**Program Design**

Without a specification code can get confused, so let's assume a spec of

1. Click the `Add` button to add a table row with a row number in the first column, several input elements in following columns, and a select element in the last column
2. All select elements should have options for entries in the `DeviceNames` array.
3. Each option should have a `value` attribute taken from the index of option text in `DeviceNames`. The example below calculates `value` using a *ones* based index but can always be changed to suite requirements.

**Changes**

1. Select elements didn't have id's. It would be possible to give them `id` or `name` attribute based on the table row they occur in, but the code snippet below does not attempt to do so.
2. `HTMLSelectElement` elements have an `add` method to add options.
3. Element objects themselves are passed as parameters to functions which need to operate on the DOM object.
4. A minor change: use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` if the content is text. While `innerHTML` may work, it parses text inserted as HTML markup.

**Snippet**

```js
var DeviceNames = new Array ("Dev1", "Dev2");

function addoption(select, text, optionValue) {
    
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = text;            
    option.value = optionValue;
    select.add(option);
}

function loadcombo(select, option_array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < option_array.length; i++) {
        var value = i+1;
        addoption (select, option_array[i], value);
    }
}

function addRow(tableID) {  
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  

  //Column 1    
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
  cell1.textContent = rowCount+1;  
  //Column 2  
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
  var element2 = document.createElement("input");  
  element2.type = "text";  
  cell2.appendChild(element2); 

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);  
  var element3 = document.createElement("input");  
  element3.type = "text";
  cell3.appendChild(element3);      

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  
  var element4 = document.createElement("input");  
  element4.type = "text";  
  cell4.appendChild(element4); 

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  cell5.appendChild(select);

  loadcombo(select, DeviceNames);
                
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Entry" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Insert Entry" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" name="button1" value="Delete Entry" onclick="removeRow('button1')" />           
          <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">  
               <TR>
                    <TD></TD>
               </TR>               
          </TABLE>
```

Comment: Let's suppose if the Table already been made and we just do have table id and index of a cell which is Combobox. How can we change the options of that Combobox with given details such as index of cell and table id.

Comment: How would you design it? For starters, what do you mean by "cell index{?

Comment: when I open the page table already been created. but Combobox not populated because it depends on another table value. So, I just want to clear the Combobox options and add new options whenever other table change the value.

Comment: table cell (column) which is Combobox

Comment: If you wish to clarify the problem, please edit the question with details. _I can't help further with this answer_ - I was thinking every table row had  a select element in column 5, and if the user can delete rows (code not shown) the index of a particular row would not stay constant.